# How to add new site dashboard layout in Alfresco 4.0.2?

Tags: layout, alfresco, dashboard, alfresco-share

I wish to create new site dashboard layout ( one full width row and second row has two equal columns ) and I want that changes to be applied to all existing users on Alfresco 4.0.2.

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Best,

D